# Excel - Formula based transpose from comma separated values to individual rows

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I maintain my CD/DVD inventory in an Excel file (Excel 2013). The data is organized as shown in below snapshot.

On each row there’s first cell mentioning the CD label and next cell holds the comma separated list of apps that I have written on it.

However I am interested in a view in which the comma separated values get transposed to rows so that there’s only one item per cell and per row as shown below.

I understand, VBA can help here easily and I do have basic VBA knowledge, however is there a possible formula based solution to transpose the data from input to output? I want to avoid Macros and also want to avoid manual process of Text To Column then Copy-Paste Transpose.

It should also trim the extra space if any after comma.

[image]

Comment: there probably is some sort of array that would work on your small data set, but if you have a much larger data set to work with I think you will struggle to find a solution without VBA

Comment: There are about 40 rows of data right now. Rows get added as and when a new optical disk is used.

Comment: @rajeev, instead of a Formula I found MACRO (VBA) is the best suitable & easier method to handle the issue. As you can find in comments **PeterH** has also suggested the VBA solution. Therefore I've posted the code which is easy to use and could easily handle small as well as *Larger INPUT comma separated rows*. It's handy and, I do believe you find it quit useful too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do it with a formula, with older than Office 365 Excel you will need a helper column.

Next to your comma delimited list(my list starts in C2) put:

```
=LEN(C1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(C1,",",""))+1+D1
```

This will keep a running total of the number of words.

[image]

Then you reference both these columns with INDEX/MATCH to reference the correct cell as the long formula gets dragged down.

The long formula is:

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(INDEX(C:C,MATCH(ROW(1:1),D:D)),",",REPT(" ",99)),(ROW(1:1)-INDEX(D:D,MATCH(ROW(1:1),D:D)))*99 +1,99))
```

Then two INDEX/MATCH returns the correct cells to be processed.

The SUBSTITUTE adds a lot of white space giving a large target for the Mid to find.

The Mid splits the long string in the white space.

The TRIM removes the extraneous white space.

[image]

---

With Office 365 you can skip the helper column and use TEXTJOIN() if the string is not too long.

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,$C$2:$C$5),",",REPT(" ",99)),(ROW(1:1)-1)*99+1,99))
```

This replaces the INDEX/MATCH with TEXTJOIN, otherwise it acts like above.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

*I would like to suggest one simple VBA (Macro) method, which is very easy to use & better than any tedious formula.*

[image]

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim xArr() As String
    Dim xAddress As String
    Dim Rg As Range
    Dim Rg1 As Range

    On Error Resume Next

    xAddress = Application.ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.Address

    Set Rg = Application.InputBox("please select the data range:", "Column to Row", xAddress, , , , , 8)

    If Rg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Set Rg = Application.Intersect(Rg, Rg.Parent.UsedRange)

    If Rg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Set Rg1 = Application.InputBox("please select output cell:", "Column to Row", , , , , , 8)

    If Rg1 Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    xArr = Split(Join(Application.Transpose(Rg.Value), ","), ",")
    Rg1.Resize(UBound(xArr) + 1) = Application.Transpose(xArr)
    Rg1.Parent.Activate
   Rg1.Resize(UBound(xArr) + 1).Select

Call TrimXcessSpaces

End Sub
```

**How it works:**

- Click **Developer TAB**, hit **Design** then **Insert**.
- Select **Command button** from **ActiveX** category and draw anywhere
  on sheet.
- Right Click **Command button** and Select **Property**.
- Find **Caption** From the list and change it to **Column To Row.**
- Close Property Window & return to Sheet.
- Double Click the Command button, you will land to VB Editor Window.
- **Copy & Paste** this Code in between **Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()**
  and **End Sub** and click **Save Icon**.
- From **VB editor** window click **File Command** and click **Close &
  Return to Microsoft Excel.**
- Click the **Design Mode** to turn it **off**.

**Now Click the on Sheet command button:**

- First **Input Box** will appear then select List **separated by comma
  in (B4:B6)** & finish with Ok.
- Second **Input Box** will appear select any **single Cell** like I did **E4** 
  & finish with Ok button.

*You find the list in Rows as shown in Screen Shot.*

**N.B.** *Adjust cell references as needed.*

**EDITED:**

*I've edited the post since **PeterH** has suggest me to remove **White Space** from the output in **Column E**.*

1. Form the Sheet Press **ALT+F11**, to open the VB Editor.
2. Find the Sheet name from Project Explorer Windows on left.
3. Select & **Right click** the Sheet name.
4. Find **Insert** from menu then click the **Module** command.
5. Copy & Paste this code & **Save** to return the Sheet.

   ```
    Option Explicit

    Sub TrimXcessSpaces()

     Dim cl As Variant

     For Each cl In Selection
        If Len(cl) > Len(WorksheetFunction.Trim(cl)) Then
            cl.Value = WorksheetFunction.Trim(cl)
        End If
     Next cl
   End Sub
   ```

**Note,** *add this code just before the **End Sub** in previous code,(check the 
  code above).*

```
Call TrimXcessSpaces
```

6. From the Sheet Click the **Command button**, output will look like shown
   below.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @PeterH,, LOL , while commenting I really missed the code to include. Now it's been added. Thanks you prompted me. :-)

Comment: +1 from me, great answer, only tiny thing missing is that spaces are still included in the output

Comment: Thanks @PeterH, for appreciating my efforts,, let me check how to adjust the spaces.

Comment: @PeterH, just check the post I've edited to remove the White Spaces from Output.

Answer (score 0):

The suggested answer didn't actually work for me. My data is messy and I have duplicates, this caused it to break down. So I came up with a different solution:
`=TRIM(TRANSPOSE(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,C2:C5),",")))`

How this works:

1. TEXTJOIN gets all of the data together in one long comma separated list.
2. TEXTSPLIT then separates each of those items forming an array of items.
3. TRANSPOSE makes those items appear in a column.
4. TRIM removes any extra spaces.

If you want to filter the data further, you can surround the list with other filter commands, like `UNIQUE`.

If you don't want to separate on commas, you can always change the delimiters in `TEXTJOIN` and `TEXTSPLIT` to whatever you want.